# how to cancel the keypad while typing inside text box in mac (Iphone Simulator)

Tags: iphone, macos, intellij-idea, ios-simulator

Like in windows, Consider we are using IntelliJ (Android Dev) If we type anything in text field, the default keypad will appear in the emulator. We can cancel it by clicking ESC button in the keyboard. In the mac, ESC button is not working if I need to cancel the keypad in Simulator(Iphone). Please provide the solution.

Comment: press enter might give you the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS does not allow the user to dismiss the keyboard like in Android, by clicking the backbutton.

You will have to code this your self, since the iOS keyboard does have an ESC key.

Answer (score 0):

You are not familiar with the `UITextField` Class . Please go through it and you would find a property of the  `UITextField` known as `ResignFirstResponder`. It is used to hide the keyboard. Now you can add it to the return of the `UITextField` according to your requirement. Hope this helps [UITextField Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)